# Scraping online social forum- not able to get date

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am currently trying to scrape this online forum: https://community.whattoexpect.com/forums/postpartum-depression.html

As you can see, the main page is a list page with all posts, and then I would have to click into each post to get the full content and the replies. The information I need for each post is:Title, Author, Date, and the message content of the post. I also need the same information for each reply to each post (author, date, and content)

The problem that I have ran into so far is that I can see the post date on the website, but not with Scrapy. Here is the element inspection:

[image]

But in Scrapy shell, there is an empty space where the date text should be:
[image]

I have tried many CSS and Xpath methods, and nothing works.

Eventually, I want my resulting CSV file to contain the original post information on the first row, and then the information for the replies on the next row.This is so that I can track interactions. And, the post title or some other message ID would be the common identifier. Here is an example:

[image]

Ok, here is my Scrapy spider so far. It is very messy because I've been trying to solve the date issue.

```
    import scrapy
```

class PeripartumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'peripartum'

```
start_urls = ['http://www.community.whattoexpect.com/forums/postpartum-depression.html']

def parse(self, response):
    for post_link in response.xpath('//*[@class="group-discussions__list__item__block"]/a/@href').extract():
        link = response.urljoin(post_link)
        yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_post)

    # Checks if the main page has a link to next page if True keep parsing.
    next_page = response.xpath('(//a[@class="page-link"])[1]/@href').extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)


def parse_thread(self, response):

    original_post = response.xpath("//*[@class='__messageContent fr-element fr-view']/p/text()").extract()
    title = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__title']/text()").extract_first()
    author_name = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__author__name']/text()").extract_first()
    timestamp = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__author__updated']/text()").extract_first()
    replies_list = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-replies__list']").getall()

    for reply in replies_list:
        # reply content
        replies = "".join(reply.xpath(".//*[@class='wte-reply__content']/p/text()").extract())
        reply_author= reply.xpath("//*[@class='wte-reply__author']/text()").extract_first()

    yield {
        "title": title,
        "post": original_post,
        "author_name": author_name,
        "replies": replies,
        "reply_author": reply_author,
        "time": timestamp
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Human readable date rendered on page by JS from attribute **data-date**. This number is [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

You can deal with it easily.

```
import datetime  # We need this module to deal with date

unixtimestamp = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__author__updated']/@data-date").extract_first()  # Extracting timestamp

unixtimestamp = int(unixtimestamp)/1000  # Removing milliseconds
timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unixtimestamp).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Date is in UTC. If you need another timezone - you have to add some hours or convert to another tz.